# class being reset on postback

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I have a class that is used in various web pages and the same class could be used twice in the same page. The class members are accessed in various parts of the code so I declared as so..

```
Public Class Page
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim UserDetails as New User
    Dim ThisMonthDD as New DeadlineDates
    Dim LastMonthDD as New DeadlineDates

    Protected Sub Page_Load()

       If Not IsPostBack Then
          UserDetails.GetUserDetails(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").Split("\")(1))
          ThisMonthDD.BaseDate = Now()
          ..........
       Else
          ..........
       End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub SomeOtherEvent()

          Tb_claimdatedeadline = ThisMonthDD.UserSubmitDeadline
          .......
    End Sub
```

How do I stop the classes from being reset on postback and be visible to all events in page class?

Comment: You could use a `Session` variable instead. Note that all variables and controls are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. [**Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx).

Comment: Tim, I'm not sure how to initialise this... For example the user class has many properties. User.isadmin, user.name, user.team etc. The use.getuserdetails method gets details from dB and populates the properties... How will I propergate this to a session? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is serializable, you can save the entire object (and its state) to session.  It would look something like this when you add it:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("currentUserDetails", UserDetails)
```

If you want to reference it later on (or update it), you should check for its existence and act accordingly, like so:

```
If HttpContext.Current.Session.Item("currentUserDetails") IsNot Nothing Then
     ' Do stuff with it here
End If
```